# How to save output from a python script not as json but a stream of objects?

Tags: python, sed

I have a python script that does some processing on a given large input file (10million rows). It then saves it as JSON.

The code I have is:

```
1   import json
2   
3   with open('inputFile') as infile:
4       data = json.load(infile)
5       for i in data:
6           #some processing...
7   
8   with open('outputFile', 'w') as outfile:
9       json.dump(data, outfile)
10   
11  infile.close()
12  outfile.close()
```

This saves it in a JSON format because of (i believe) line-9:

```
[{...},
{...},
{...},
{...}]
```

My question is: **How do I NOT save it in a json format...? Is there any other way as
I want my outputFile be like:**

```
{...}
{...}
{...}
{...}
```

Alternatively, I tried using SED to remove the commas at the end of each line and square brackets but got the error:

SED COMMAND: `sed 's/^\[//g; s/\]$//g; s/,$//g' inputFile > outputFile`

ERROR: `sed: regex input buffer length larger than INT_MAX`

Comment: The data seems to be a list so you could iterate through it and dump each item in json format on a separate line.

Comment: Hmm, was thinking of that but couldn't get the hang of it, could you possibly give me a small example based on my code please?

Comment: @oguzismail - I have updated the title. Thanks for suggestion and downvote.

Comment: You already have for-loop for processing. You can create a similar one and dump each single item in it.